# Why supernode approch results wrong answer?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image][image]I have to find v1 using node voltage method could any one tell me what is the mistake so I am getting wrong answer i.e 78V but real answer which is given in book is 54V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKdxUD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your circuit (in the picture) is hard to read. There is a circuit drawing tool available, Ctrl-M. That might help.

Comment: @Tyler we have to find voltage across R5 with positive polarity towards node3 ix is the current along R2 10ohms.I have applied KCL at node3 and treated node2 and node4 as a supernode.One equation is found from node 3 and two from super node but i dont know why i am getting wrong answer..

Comment: Is your dependent current source equation supposed to be I = 3 * I_R2

Comment: No it is I=3*(current through R2 lets say Ix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I have missed something, you are not 100% consistent in your naming of things. IE in the hand written drawing you have the center node labeled "1" but in the schematic it is labeled "2".

Anyways, the answer I get agrees with the given answers. I solved it using 4 current loops. Your mistake is when you multiply equation (i) by 3, you do not multiply 1620 by 3.

You have
(i)
$$
V_1 -5V_3 +10V_4 -1620 = 0
$$

You then attempt to multiply by 3 to eliminate \$ V_3 \$.

You have

$$
3V_1 -15V_3 +30V_4 = 1620
$$

But it should be

$$
3V_1 -15V_3 +30V_4 = 4860
$$

HTH